# What is the fastest way to detect two points in 2D space with biggest distance between them?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I need to get two points that have biggest distance between.

The easiest method is to compute distance between each of them, but that solution would have an quadratic complexity.

So i'm looking for any faster solution.

Comment: Just to know, do you see O(n^2) as an exponential complexity?

Comment: Around 1k of points. And fixed exponential => quadratic.

Comment: What level of complexity is acceptable? if all level as @Tom Zych mentioned you can use rotating calipers algorithm in convex hull, but if important thing is to use simple method and accuracy is not very important you can have some approximation on optimal, Also O(n^2) for 1K is not bad, it's fast enough but if you iterate over this 1k it can be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

1 Determine the convex hull of the set of points.
2 Find the longest distance between points on the hull.

That should allow you to ignore all points not on the hull when checking for distance.

Comment: This is a good solution but too hard to implement, i think. And Quadratic complexity isn't that bad.

Comment: @McOmghall Too hard to implement? Do more algorithms, man... and more programming... and more SO.

Comment: I think this solution also has an n-square complexity as the basic solution (i.e finding distance between each two points)

Comment: @suat No because you can do a double traversal of the points in O(N) time.

Comment: @quasiverse I considered the operations to determine a convex hull. It is also possible that I am missing a point.

Comment: @suat Sorry, what do you mean by "considered the operations"?

Comment: @quasiverse I didn't understand 20 min ago the formula for constructing the set. I think I understand it now. Yes, it's easy.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on rossom's answer:

1. Find the convex hull of the points which can be found in O(n log n) time with an algorithm like Graham's Scan or O(n log h) time with other algorithm's which I assume are harder to implement
2. Start at a point, say A, and loop through the other points to find the one furthest from it, say B.
3. Advance A to the next point and advance B until it is furthest from A again. If this distance is larger than the one in part 2, store it as the largest. Repeat until you have looped through all points A in the set

Parts 2 and 3 take amortized O(n) time and therefore the overall algorithm takes O(n log n) or O(n log h) time depending on how much time you can be bothered spending on implementing convex hull.

This is great and all but if you only have a few thousand points (like you said), O(n^2) should work fine (unless you're executing it many times).

Comment: Shouldn't the part 3 take O(N^2)?